# "Adaptive" data structure

Tags: data-structures

Are there any known "adaptive data structures", for example, which can change on-fly from array to linked-list, or from the latter to binary tree depending on access patterns to it?
For example: small number of elements: stay as array.
5-10 elements: convert itself to linked list.
More elements: convert to binary tree.

Comment: What do you mean by "are there"? You've described it, ergo it exists; writing out pseudo-code seems to be an easy exercise. The question is, does it gain you anything? What goal are you pursueing? Google "self-adjusting data structure" for starters; they don't do what you describe, but *do* restructure themselves in reaction to access patterns.

Comment: There are probably popular solutions, so I would love to hear about them...

Comment: Something like splay tree? With change between linked-list and array something more is needed - the VM or own function maintaining such conversions would be needed (data structure not matter how sophisticated does not care / have insight into memory used), but splay tree adapts on every search. Taking linked-list - it can be implemented using array (flat 2n elements, two dimensional 2 x n) but where and how elements are stored is not part of structure.

Comment: I think a B tree of order 7, say, can be thought of as an array for the first 6 elements being inserted. Does that qualify?

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of the question is, do you want to use it or is it more academic interest? There is, for example, the k-dimensional PH-Tree, which has 3 different 'modes' in which an internal node can be represented. Roughly speaking: for small nodes it uses a list of key-value pairs, for medium nodes it uses an array of values (size=2^k; keys are implicit in the array position), for large nodes it splits nodes into a sub-tree. This minimizes memory usage while facilitating dynamic updates. See www.phtree.org.

Comment: There is also the Hybrid-Tree, which I think also uses internally different modes (search for "hybrid tree index").